# How to pass parameters to modal when i call it programmatically?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, parameter-passing

I call bootstrap modal programmatically like this

```js
$('#confirmModal').modal()
```

But when i do so, "event" in:

```js
$('#confirmModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget); 
})
```

doesn't have "relatedTarget" but i need it. How to pass it using $('#confirmModal').modal()

Comment: If you are calling modal on page load like `$('#confirmModal').modal()` then there will be no `$(event.relatedTarget)`, `$(event.relatedTarget)` only works when you click the modal trigger button to open the modal.

Comment: And there is no way to pass it? I don't call it inside page load but inside click event on another html object. Any way to pass parameters to event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set `relatedTarget`, it is a readonly property of the event. `show.bs.modal` is BTW fired by the bootstrap modal itself, so either way you are lost.

But why not trigger the `click` event of the modal trigger button programmtically, it would be the *exact* same as calling `modal()`, and then the `relatedTarget` is present :

```js
$("#button").click();
```

Under the assumption that you have well formed "modal trigger button" like this :

```html
<button id="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal">show modal</button>
```

see here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/y3s1t7ea/**

Comment: Good answer but i wanted to pass params using another JS. So sad that it's not possible to do without crutches. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not [officially documented](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods) it is possible to pass a second argument to `modal()` which acts as the related target:

```
$('#confirmModal').modal('show', $('#someButton'));
```

Then you can use the event handler as it would have been triggered by a button or whatever:

```
$('#confirmModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = event.relatedTarget; // should be set now
})
```

This should work with at least with Bootstrap 3.3.x and I guess also with 4.0.x.