# Bootstrap modal on button click needs full reload of modal window

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I need to full reload modal window on clicking on button(span here)
Right now clicking is opening modal window and closing modal window.

if i use this code:

```
$('#youtubeModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $('#youtubeModal').modal('toggle')
})
```

It's just reopening modal window, but i need full reload.

**I have rigth now:**

1. I press the button.
2. Modal shown with all working fine.
3. I press the button
4. Modal hidden.
5. I press the button.
6. Modal open and loading again ajax and work fine.

**I need**
delete 4. and 5. :

1. I press the button.
2. Modal shown with all working fine.
3. I press the button
4. Modal reopen and reloading ajax and work fine.

   ```
    <div class="modal fade" id="youtubeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#youtubeModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            let button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            let youtubeUrl = button.data('url') // Extract info from data-* attributes

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['youtube/index'])?>',
                type: 'post',
                data: {youtubeUrl: youtubeUrl},
                success(response) {
                    // Add response in Modal body
                    $('.modal-body').html(response);
                    //$('#exampleModal').html(response);
                    // Display Modal
                    //$('#exampleModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
   ```

Comment: You want the modal to be populated from the AJAX response when someone opens the modal?

Comment: NO, the modal window is workig and populating from the AJAX. I need to full reload the modal when i click on button. Right now the modal is opeinig(loading ajax) and closing and opening(loading ajax) and closing. I need ajax do not closing and reopening and reloading enstead of losing

Comment: You need first to check if there are data in you modal body and if not then do the ajax call

Comment: Why i need to check modal body empty or not? My code up threre is fully working: 
1. I press the button.
2. Modal shown with all working fine.
3. I press the button
4. Modal hidden.
5. I press the button.
6. Modal open and loading again ajax and work fine.

I need delete 4. and 5. points:

1. I press the button.
2. Modal shown with all working fine.
3. I press the button
6. Modal reopen and reloading ajax and work fine.

Comment: On step 3. I press the button, it is the same "span" button or button in modal?

Comment: The same span button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks you need a custom trigger and do it programmatically
because the default BS data-toggle trigger has another logic

```
<span id="play-button" class="fa fa-play-circle play-button" data-url="watch?v=ik7ysDGWbcw" onclick="showYoutubeModal(this)">click me</span>


<div class="modal fade" id="youtubeModal" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var youtubeModal = $('#youtubeModal').modal({'show': false});
youtubeModal.on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   let button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    let youtubeUrl = button.data('url');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['youtube/index'])?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: {youtubeUrl: youtubeUrl},
        success(response) {
        // Add response in Modal body
        $('.modal-body').html(response);
        //$('#exampleModal').html(response);
        // Display Modal
        //$('#exampleModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});

function showYoutubeModal(trigger) {
    // here you can call modal function programmatically
    // depending on your needs
    youtubeModal.modal('show', $(trigger));
}
</script>
```

Also more info you can find here

[How to pass parameters to modal when i call it programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242445/how-to-pass-parameters-to-modal-when-i-call-it-programmatically)